# Is it possible configuring working directory with multiple data folders

Tags: redis

I've currently installed Redis on VM which has two mounted disks. I'd like to use those two mounted disks as working directories for Redis.

So is it possible to configure Redis working directory `dir` with multiple folder locations?

Thanks!

AVR

Answer (score 0):

NO, you **CANNOT** do that.

Redis can only hold data that fits into memory. Normally that size is much smaller than the size of a disk, and there's no need to use multiple disks to extend the storage.

In some cases, multiple disks might help, e.g. Redis is dumping data set to disk while syncing with slaves, Redis dumps both AOF and RDB files. In these cases, there are multiple readers or writers working at the same time, and that might cause performance issues (i.e. too many disk seeks).

However, since Redis focuses on in-memory store, I'm not sure if that's a big problem to concern.